# Several redeclaration errors occur when AFDownloadRequestOperation is added

Tags: multithreading, uiimageview, uiimage, nsoperation, afnetworking

When I add `AFDownloadRequestOperation` I get several errors that result in the inability for me to successfully build my project...

These errors all seem to be of a redeclaration nature. My first mind is to go into the files that display the error and individually delete the other declarations.

But I figured that it may cause more errors and/or not be the best method to resolve my issue. Is anyone familiar with this issue?

I have attached a screenshot of what I see.

Comment: I don't see a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that Xcode is complaining about there being multiple files in the project that declare the `@interface` for `AFDownloadRequestOperation`. Note that `AFDownloadRequestOperation` has never been a part of the standard AFNetworking library, so I would suggest that you make sure that you are using the most up-to-date version of the canonical source available.

You may find [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) to be helpful for managing your dependencies, as an alternative to manually adding source files to your project.